# Coldfusion & SQL to create recursive tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, coldfusion, tree

**UPDATE**

I have a very unique case where I am given this from my SQL database.

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| LVL  | LVL_1 | LVL_2 | LVL_3 | LVL_4 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| PHIL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| PHIL | BOB   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| PHIL | BOB   | BILL  | NULL  | NULL  |
| PHIL | BOB   | BILL  | JEN   | NULL  |
| PHIL | BOB   | BILL  | JEN   | JOE   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The last LVL column that contains a name represents the person.

For example, this represents PHIL

```
| PHIL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
```

And this represents JEN

```
| PHIL | BOB   | BILL  | JEN   | NULL  |
```

And this represents JOE (since he is the last level)

```
| PHIL | BOB   | BILL  | JEN   | JOE  |
```

**My ultimate goal is to return this data into a JSON tree structure from ColdFusion like this when I query for 'PHIL':**

```
{
  name: 'PHIL',
  parent: NULL,
  level: 0,
  groups: [
    {
      name: 'BOB',
      parent: 'PHIL',
      level: 1,
      groups: [
        {
          name: 'BILL',
          parent: 'BOB',
          level: 2,
          groups: [
            {
              name: 'JEN',
              parent: 'BILL',
              level: 3,
              groups: [
                {
                  name: 'JOE',
                  parent: 'JEN',
                  level: 4,
                  groups: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**If I query for 'BILL', I can only see the the tree data below him like this:**

```
    {
      name: 'BILL',
      parent: 'BOB',
      level: 2,
      groups: [
        {
          name: 'JEN',
          parent: 'BILL',
          level: 3,
          groups: [
            {
              name: 'JOE',
              parent: 'JEN',
              level: 4,
              groups: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'd like to write some SQL command that would be able to produce a tree structure of this data. If it's not possible, I'd like to at least reformat (with SQL commands) the original data into:

```
+------+--------+
| NAME | PARENT |
+------+--------+
| PHIL | NULL   |
| BOB  | PHIL   |
| BILL | BOB    |
| JEN  | BILL   |
| JOE  | JEN    |
+------+--------+
```

So I can perhaps restructure this into a tree data using ColdFusion by following this tutorial http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1069-ask-ben-simple-recursion-example.htm

Is it possible? Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Step 1 will be to write a query that gets your data.  To get help with that, edit your question to show the relevent parts of your database structure.

Comment: Look at how CTEs work: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx. But also check whether that's the best hierarchical model to use. Whatever you decide, the DB processing belongs in the DB, not on the CFML side though.

Comment: Does the order of the "groups" array matter?

Comment: The order of the groups array doesn't matter

Comment: They are the column names given from the table of the SQL database

Comment: and 4 is the maximum level?

Comment: Yup 4 is the maximum level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69248/discussion-between-henry-and-user3314402).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
q = queryNew("LTM,LTM_1,LTM_2,LTM_3,LTM_4");

queryAddRow(q);
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM", "OSTAPOWER");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_1", "VENKAT");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_2", "LYNN");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_3", "SMITH");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_4", "HARTLEY");

queryAddRow(q);
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM", "OSTAPOWER");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_1", "VENKAT");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_2", "LYNN");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_3", "SMITH");
QuerySetCell(q, "LTM_4", "SHREVE");

function collect(q) {
    var data = {};
    for (var row in q)
    {
        var varName = "data";
        for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            var col = i == 0 ? "LTM" : "LTM_#i#";
            var name = row[col];
            if (len(name))
                varName = listAppend(varName, name, ".");
            else
                break;
        }
        setVariable(varName, {});
    }

    return data;
}

function transform(tree, nodeName, level=0, parent="") 
{
    if (structIsEmpty(tree))
        return "";

    var node = {
        'name': nodeName,
        'parent': len(parent) ? parent : javacast("null",""),
        'level': javacast("int", level),
        'groups': []
    };

    var branch = tree[nodeName];

    for (var child in branch)
        arrayAppend(node.groups, transform(branch, child, level+1, nodeName));

    return node;
}

c=collect(q);

writeDump(transform(c,'OSTAPOWER'));
</cfscript>
```

Run it: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=c8YMvGXG

Then just `serializeJSON()` the result returned from `transform()`.

Comment: I just tried running it but I got this error: "There was an error parsing your code. This usually indicates a missing ; or another compile time syntax error. Check your syntax and try again." Do you know what could it be? But thank you so much for taking the time to do all this.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if your code is doing this already (since I run an error), but I forgot to include one last important feature. I didn't want to confuse you in anyway and so I thought about explaining to you step by step. Say that perhaps I am searching for Ostapower, I'd like to create a tree menu for only people under him (no Amoroso, Saxena, and other LTM level 0). If I am Smith, I can only see tree data of the LTM levels below him (no Ostapower, Vencat, or Lynn). Hopefully you can help, but if you don't have time, I certainly do not mind. You've helped me more than enough already!!

Comment: run on trycf.com again.  The code runs fine.  And yes, it does only return `OSTAPOWER`, see the last line.